# Animating a circle filling from bottom to top by a dynamic percentage

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a program that represents the percent of people belonging to a certain segment (think pie chart). However, instead of using a pie chart I want to draw labeled circles and fill the circle with a color commiserate with a percentage. That part I've figured out.

However, the values for the circles can change in response to user input, and I'd love to have an animation that causes the "fill" of the circle to rise or fall as the input is changed. I'm primarily a backend dev, and have almost no experience with animations, I feel like I'm spinning my wheels.

My front-end is React. Currently each circle is a React component that I pass a "percentage" property to. I then assign a linear gradient to the circle that varies depending on the percentage passed. This fills the circles the appropriate amount.

Almost all animations (if you can really call them that) that I've used in the past have used transitions. However, my research has led me to believe that linear-gradients cannot be transitioned - which leaves me in a place where I either have to redo my circle code (which I'm open to, just don't know how) or figure out a workaround to animate a linear gradient.

```
render() {
    let circleStyle = {
      background: `linear-gradient(transparent ${100-this.props.percent}%, ${this.props.color} ${100-this.props.percent}%)`
    };

    return (
      <div className="circle-container">
        <div className="circle" style={circleStyle} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        <div className="circle-info">
          <p className="circle-text">{this.props.percent}%</p>
          <p className="circle-text-hidden">CU Avg: {this.props.industryPercent}%</p>
          {strike}
        </div>
        </div>
        <h1>{this.props.segmentName}</h1>

      </div>
    )
```

Hoping I can get some sage React/CSS-Guru advice about the best way to approach this. It's in that weird valley of something that FEELS like it should be the simplest thing in the world, but which I can't stop banging my head against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend placing a second div inside of the circle and animating the height of that, which can be transitioned with CSS.  It's tough to tell exactly where to put it without seeing the CSS and how it appears, but I'd imagine it could look something like this:

```
render() {
    let gradient = background: `linear-gradient(transparent , ${this.props.color} 100%)`;


    return (
      <div className="circle-container">
        <div className="circle" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        <div className="circle-fill" style={{ background: gradient, height: this.props.percent + '%'}}
        <div className="circle-info">
          <p className="circle-text">{this.props.percent}%</p>
          <p className="circle-text-hidden">CU Avg: {this.props.industryPercent}%</p>
          {strike}
        </div>
        </div>
        <h1>{this.props.segmentName}</h1>

      </div>
    )
```

You would need other CSS to make this work.  I'd recommend making `circle` `position: relative` and the `circle-fill` `position: absolute` with a width of 100%. You may need to do more adjustments to the `z-index` to display your content properly at the same time as well.

Comment: Thanks! Like you predicted this took some doing with the CSS. I was leaning heavily on flexbox before and the necessity of overlapping multiple divs meant some rejiggering of my setup. Things are working like I want now!